# I/O operation on closed file in Python def

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I know this is a repeat but I've looked through the answers and none of them make sense to why I'm getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file in this specific python 2.7 function written here.

No error when separating this out to a stand alone sciptlet of:

```
import hashlib
import sys

sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()

filename = 'result.txt'

with open(filename,"rb") as f:
# Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
    for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096),b""):
        sha256_hash.update(byte_block)
    print(sha256_hash.hexdigest())
f.close()
```

But when I put this into a defined function I get a ValueError on the print function.

```
def sha256hashcheck():
    with open( 'goldresult.txt' ,"rb") as f:
        # Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
        for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096),b""):
            sha256_hash.update(byte_block)
        print(sha256_hash.hexdigest())
    f.close()

sha256hashcheck()
```

All the other defined functions run the close() method before exiting the function, plus I make a test file on the side that no function calls and use that as the open in the def and I still get the ValueError exception

```
  File "parse-o365-ip-addrs.py", line 61, in sha256hashcheck
    print(sha256_hash.hexdigest())
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Any pointers or suggestions?

TY

---

Here is my entire script .. yes I'm new to python .. :)

```
# Initial code - https://gist.github.com/cdodd/7679fb9c5f2a2e4700c7a9c7a53e2a19 (cdodd)
import xmltodict
from socket import inet_ntoa
from struct import pack
import sys
import urllib
import hashlib

# Read from URL
data = urllib.urlopen('https://support.content.office.net/en-us/static/O365IPAddresses.xml').read()
doc = xmltodict.parse(data)
# Read from local file
# doc = xmltodict.parse(open('/path/to/file.xml').read())

# set your variables
subnettestVar = 'test.txt'
subnetresultVar = 'result.txt'
subnetgoldVar = 'goldresult.txt'
sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()

#define your functions or classes

def calcDottedNetmask(mask):
    bits = 0xffffffff ^ (1 << 32 - mask) - 1
    return inet_ntoa(pack('>I', bits))

# Work to be done, if x['@name'] still shells exception (KeyError) on 'OneNote' because OneNote has no IPv4 address
# Still need to work out either .get (dict) or try - exception errorhandling for that issue 
def getsubnets():
    sys.stdout = open( subnettestVar , 'w')
    for x in doc['products']['product']:
        if x['@name'] in ['o365', 'Identity', 'Planner', 'ProPlus', 'Yammer', 'Teams', 'SPO', 'LYO', 'WAC']:
            for y in x['addresslist']:
                if y['@type'] == 'IPv4':
                    for ip in y['address']:
                        if '/' not in ip:
                            ip, dot_mask = (ip, '255.255.255.255')
                        else:
                            ip, cidr_mask = ip.split('/')
                            dot_mask = calcDottedNetmask(int(cidr_mask))
                        print 'network-object ' + ip + ' ' + dot_mask
                    print
    sys.stdout.close()

def removeblanklines():
    with open( subnettestVar ,'r+') as file, open( subnetresultVar ,"w") as outfile:
        for i in file.readlines():
            if not i.strip():
                continue
            if i:   
                outfile.write(i)
    file.close()
    outfile.close()

def sha256hashcheck():
    with open( 'goldresult.txt' ,"rb") as f:
        # Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
        for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096),b""):
            sha256_hash.update(byte_block)
        print(sha256_hash.hexdigest())
    f.close()

#Run your full program with all functions, classes and variables

getsubnets()
removeblanklines()
sha256hashcheck()
```

Comment: So, first off: You're correctly using `with` statements, so you don't need to (and shouldn't) explicitly call `close` on your files. The whole point of the `with` is to provide guaranteed, deterministic cleanup. Beyond that, the error you're getting is for the `print` line (`hexdigest` doesn't use a file at all), which indicates you've closed `sys.stdout` somehow. Are you sure you've provided complete code?

Comment: Also, is this really Python 2.7 specific? Your code is written in a Python 3 compatible manner (properly prefixing the sentinel for two arg `iter` with `b`, using parentheses with `print`, etc.). Nothing about it is *incompatible* with Python 2.7, but I'm not seeing anything specific to 2.7 here either.

Comment: when you sure the function, where did u declare sha256_hash? because I try your code on python 2.7 and in both case is working, in the function case it's just complaining that sha256_hash is not defined

Comment: @ShadowRanger I would read that tag as a request for an answer that works in Python 2.7.

Comment: @chepner: Yeah, but I figured I'd check. If they already know how to write cross-compatible code, it's usually not a big deal to convert Py3 answers to Py2.7. They also *only* tagged it as `python-2.7` (I added the general `python` tag), so I was trying to figure out if they had some reason to believe the problem was 2.7 specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making an answer from my comment:

The error you're getting is for the `print` (`hexdigest` doesn't use a file at all), which indicates you've closed `sys.stdout` somehow. As you stated, your real code included `sys.stdout.close()`, which would make all default `print` calls fail with this error. Don't close `sys.stdout` and/or pass `file=somefileobj` as a keyword argument to `print` so it doesn't use `sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

All, thanks for the pointers, ShadowRanger hit the nail on the head - me being stupid and calling sys.stdout.close() .

Created a proper "with" "as" to open the file and properly call file open, just had to fuss with the print lines and call filename.write instead of relying on print statements which are console instead of file specific.

Please feel free to claim an Answer if you want ...

TY